# System.InvalidOperationException error when trying to connect to SQL Database from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, database, oracleclient

When trying to open connection to SQL database, I am getting the error below:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attempt to load Oracle client
>   libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when
>   running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client.

Can't seem to get it fixed.

Comment: If you want to avoid such compatibility issues, you can use the Oracle managed client which does not require the local Oracle client

Comment: Did you try switching your build to x86?

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc No, not quite sure how to do this

Comment: @Lyrrad25 Open the solution in Visual Studio. On the menu bar, click on Project and select the bottom item (it should say "YourProjectName" Properties). Click on the "Build" tab on the left. When that page opens, choose "x86" in the "Platform target:" dropdown. Save and try debugging it again.